# EditText loses focus when typing in it

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, focus

I added a bunch of EditTexts programatically to a scrollview. When the keyboard shows up it resize the views, including the scrollview, and some of the edittexts get covered by it, **no problem**, I just scroll to find them. **The problem** comes when I type in any of the edittexts, the focus is lost, to be clear the view is still focused but out of the visible range. It's like typing in it would resize again the scrollview before the keyboard showed up and therefore, the view is realocated.  I already look for solutions in the web, but nobody seems to have this issue.

**Note: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" won't do the trick**

Any idea of what is happening ? or what can I do?

Here is some of the code:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_edittexts; ++i) {
  editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setInputType(1);
        editText.setImeOptions(6);
        editText.setHint("Example: aeiou");
        editText.setY(heightET);
        editText.setX(widthET);
        editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.addView(editText);
        heightTV = heightTV + 100;
        heightET = heightET + 100;
   }
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context=".FirstActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Please insert whatever"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
    android:layout_width="379dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="StartNextActivity"
    android:text="Continue"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

So instead of setting the height of the view with `setY(int)` I used `setMaxHeight(int)`